# android animation : animate line

Tags: android, android-animation

I am new to android animations,I want to implement a line animation which is a bottom line of edit text in android.when focus is on email field,when focus goes to password field,I want the bottom line of android text edit to animate and goes under password field.as shown in below.I tried using path animations, But i dont know how to animate the line in path animation with circular path.Please help.Thank You in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe it would be a good way to use Android Vector drawables with android-pathview animation https://github.com/geftimov/android-pathview

where you will have login and password inside one layout, and this drawable animation would be as a background for this layout

Answer (score 0):

These animations are **achieved using vector based drawables** in android. Specifically SVG (scalable vector graphics).

These are **simply an xml file with path data** and you can then **manipulate the values using object animator** to achieve desired animations. Finally connect it with another drawable xml.

**Here is the sample implementation :**

//example xml vector path data file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:viewportWidth="170" 

android:viewportHeight="170" 

android:width="500dp" 

android:height="500dp"> <path 

android:name="head" 

android:fillColor="@color/

android_green" 

android:pathData="M85,40 c10,0 20,0 30,0 c0,-5 -10,-20 -30,-20 c-20,0 -30,15 -30,20 c10,0 20,0 30,0"/>
 </vector>
```

//example object animator file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<objectAnimator android:duration="@integer/morphing_time" 

android:propertyName="pathData" 

android:valueType="pathType" 

android:valueFrom="M85,40 c10,0 20,0 30,0 c0,-5 -10,-20 -30,-20 c-20,0 -30,15 -30,20 c10,0 20,0 30,0" 

android:valueTo="M108,35 c5.587379,-6.7633 9.348007,-16.178439 8.322067,-25.546439 c-8.053787,0.32369 -17.792625,5.36682 -23.569427,12.126399 c-5.177124,5.985922 -9.711121,15.566772 -8.48777,24.749359 c8.976891,0.69453 18.147476,-4.561718 23.73513,-11.329308"/> 

<objectAnimator 

android:duration="@integer/morphing_time" 

android:propertyName="fillColor" 

android:valueFrom="@color/

android_green" 

android:valueTo="@color/apple_black" />
 </set>
```

//now animate it like this in drawables folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 

android:drawable="@drawable/

android_logo_vector_morphable"> 

<target android:animation="@animator/head_leaf_transition" 

android:name="head"/> 
</animated-vector>
```

**Source:** [Lewis Mac Geary](https://lewismcgeary.github.io/posts/animated-vector-drawable-pathMorphing/)

Do let me know if this info helps you.